# How to write this query in MDX Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx

I would nee some help for writing the MDX Query.

Below is the my sql query

```
select ConditionPrevalenceKey, PopulationConditionCnt, TotalPopulationCnt, PrevalencePercent from fact.ConditionPrevalence
where ProviderID is null and ClinicID is null and ProductID is null and HealthGroupID is null and PCPID is null
and DateKey = 20121231
```

how can i write this in mdx query. Lets say my fact.conditionprevalene table is my fact table and having the measure

Suggest me?

Comment: can any one suggest me